# C++ to matlab conversion

Tags: c++, matlab

I need to convert some C++ code into the matlab
in the C++ there is following statement:

```
static double *L[2];
for (int y=0;y<2;y++)
   L[y] = new double[size];
```

in matlab I'll need to initialize the L parameter with some initial value like 0.
Can you please explain what does the C++ code means?

I need the same for the following:

```
static double **a[2];
for (int x=0;x<2;x++)
{
   a[x] = new double*[size];
   for (int y=0;y<size;y++)
   {
     a[x][y] = new double[numstates];
   }
}
```

BR

Comment: The 1st in Matlab: `zeros(2,size)`; the 2nd in Matlab: `zeros(2,size,numstates)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you please explain what does the C++ code means?

The first snippet is just initializing a `(2 * size)` matrix of double-precision floating point numbers.

The second snippet is doing the same, but it's initializing a `(2 * size * numstates)` matrix.

Comment: so for the first one i should set L =zeros(2,size); and for the second one a = zeros(2,size,numstates);

right?

Answer (score 1):

L is an array of two arrays, each of them is an array of `size` doubles. It's the same as

```
L[0] = new double[size]; 
L[1] = new double[size];
```

You may interpret L as a `2`x`size` matrix.

Likewise, `a` is `2`x`size`x`numstates` matrix of `double`s.